# Optional build step in meta-runner in Teamcity

Tags: unit-testing, build, teamcity, mstest

We created a custom meta-Runner that we then use in various build configuration.

The problem I'm having currently is that few steps (like Running mstest) in meta-runner do not apply to all the projects. Is there a way in meta-runner I can say that the build step is optional(probably based on a variable). I know I can create 2 meta-runners(1 with test and other without) but I would like to avoid it unless there is no other option.

The error I'm getting is "No assemblies, run configuration and test metadata were found" for the projects that do not have unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to do it with a variable unless you do a custom script.

But, it's probably a bit simpler than that, because you can disable inherited steps in your build configurations.

Using your build configuration *(created from the template)* that won't need unit tests,

1. Go to Administration: Build Steps
2. Find the step that executes the tests (or any step you want to disable)
3. Under the `more` dropdown at the right side of the step, you should see the option to disable the step.

*I'm going from memory here; I would give a screen shot but I do not have access to those servers currently.*

This will not affect the template at all, it simply disables the step for this build configuration.

Comment: Yes you are right but Sorry I forgot to mention that I created the template from a Meta Runner we created, so the template doesn't have that build step but the Meta Runner has. I will update the question above. Thanks.

Comment: with the config with the extra step: 1. detach from the template; 2. extract the template; this creates a new template with the step. with your other build configs: 1. detatch from the old template; 2. attach to the new template; 3. disable the build step.

Comment: But that means I will end up with 2 different templates. I'm going to try to use powershell to run the tests based on a parameter. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: No, you still have one template; you extract the new template `T2` from the project `ProjB` with the extra step; associate your project without the extra step `ProjA` to this new template `T2`. Both projects are now attached to the new template `T2`, so delete your old template `T1`. Then in your project `ProjA` that doesn't need the extra step, (disable) the build step in question. It will have all of the steps that the template `T2` has but only runs the enabled ones. Updates to the template `T2` will affect both `ProjA` and `ProjB` but will not turn that step back on, you control that.

Comment: Thanks Damon but I don't have my build steps in template. I have them in custom meta-runner and then I use the meta-runner to create a build step in a template so I can't disable steps.